# JS | Get names of the friends from a user who logged into my site via Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

Is it nowadays possible with JS to retrieve the names (and iterate through them) of a users friendlist?

I find a lot of tutorials from 2011, but they don't work anymore, likely because the API of Facebook has changed a lot since then.

When I call the following API I just receive how many friends a user has, but without names, even without IDs and other information.

```
FB.api('/me/friends?access_token=TOKEN', {fields: 'name,id,location,birthday'}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the current [api reference for /user/friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/friends)

> Permissions
>
> - A user access token with user_friends permission is required to view    the current person's friends.
> - This will only return any friends who    have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request.
> - If a friend of the person declines the user_friends permission, that    friend will not show up in the friend list for this person.

So until that user's friends also use your app and allow the user_friends permission all you will get is the count.

When in doubt about a sites api always read their api reference.

Facebook also keeps a [changelog of their api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0), so it is a good idea to keep up with that as well.